# How to dynamically create columns in datatable and assign values to it?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, vb.net-2010

I will have to create columns in datatable during runtime and assign values to it. How can i do it in vb.net. Any sample please...

Answer (score 27):

If you want to create dynamically/runtime data table in VB.Net then you should follow these steps as mentioned below :

- Create Data table object.
- Add columns into that data table object.
- Add Rows with values into the object.

For eg.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable

dt.Columns.Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", GetType(String))
dt.Columns.Add("LastName", GetType(String))

dt.Rows.Add(1, "Test", "data")
dt.Rows.Add(15, "Robert", "Wich")
dt.Rows.Add(18, "Merry", "Cylon")
dt.Rows.Add(30, "Tim", "Burst")
```

Comment: If i dont know how many columns i will have to create, how can you fix the columns like dt.Rows.Add(1, "Test", "data") ??? there can be even 10 columns. How ? Thnx

Answer (score 3):

What have you tried, what was the problem?

Creating [`DataColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.aspx) and add values to a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) is straight forward:

```
Dim dt = New DataTable()
Dim dcID = New DataColumn("ID", GetType(Int32))
Dim dcName = New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String))
dt.Columns.Add(dcID)
dt.Columns.Add(dcName)
For i = 1 To 1000
    dt.Rows.Add(i, "Row #" & i)
Next
```

**Edit**:

If you want to read a xml file and load a DataTable from it, you can use [`DataTable.ReadXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.readxml.aspx).

Comment: @Anuya: Those columns **are** dynamic (`New DataColumn....`). If that isn't helful you need to provide more informations what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have a XML. when i read each node of XML, i have to create a column in data table. Where Datatable column name = NodeName and Datatable Column value = Node value. Since the No. of nodes in XNL can vary each time, i have to make it such a way that creating of columns and assigning values to datatable should be generic

Comment: @Anuya: Then use [DataTable.ReadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.readxml.aspx).

Comment: Reading an XML is not my problem. My Question is different. I cant do as you advised because the XML will have lot of sub nodes and Datatab;e.ReadXML will not get a section out of entire XML.

Comment: @Anuya: Have you tried [`DataSet.ReadXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/804ky201) instead which should create DataTables for every sub-node?

Comment: Even that could not be done... Error : The table (add) cannot be the child table to itself in nested relations.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13147/discussion-between-anuya-and-tim-schmelter)

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Hey Tim, I was wondering if there was any reason why you wouldn't call the [`Add(String, Type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/730zyedy(v=vs.110).aspx) overload instead of taking two steps to first delcare the column and then add it with [`Add(DataColumn)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55b10992(v=vs.110).aspx)?  I've been trying to move our code base from the later to the former, but you seem like a smart chap, so I was wondering if there was something I was missing.

Comment: @kyle: no, there is no difference apart from the fact that you can access all properties if  you have the DataColumn. Since the question was about columns i thought it would be better to initialize and add them instead of using the string/type overload which does that implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of creating a datatable with columns, and some ways of setting the content of the columns without knowing them in advance:

If you read your data from some sort of File, you only have to assign the correct datatype to each column.

```
  Dim dtblDynamic As New DataTable()
  ' Create Columns based on some input data.
  For Each tupI As (strName As String, dtype As Type) In {("String Column", GetType(String)), ("Integer Column", GetType(Integer)), ("another String Column", GetType(String))}
     dtblDynamic.Columns.Add(tupI.strName, tupI.dtype)
  Next

  ' Create Rows based on some other input data.
  ' if input data has format columnName -> value:
  Dim drowNew As DataRow = dtblDynamic.NewRow()
  drowNew.Item("String Column") = "String Column - row0"
  drowNew.Item("Integer Column") = 3
  dtblDynamic.Rows.Add(drowNew)
  drowNew = dtblDynamic.NewRow
  drowNew.Item("another String Column") = "blabla"
  drowNew.Item("Integer Column") = -100
  dtblDynamic.Rows.Add(drowNew)

  ' if data for all Columns is present:
  dtblDynamic.Rows.Add({"string Col3", 42, "anotherStringCol3"})
  dtblDynamic.Rows.Add("string Col4", 43, "anotherStringCol3")
```