# Expected type is Int32. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: vb.net, datatable

On this code:

```
    Public Const NameColumn As String = "nameColumn"
    ...
    Dim dataTable As New System.Data.DataTable
    DataTable.Columns.Add(NameColumn, Type.GetType("System.String"))
    DataTable.Columns.Add(AddressColumn, Type.GetType("System.String"))
    DataTable.Columns.Add(CityColumn, Type.GetType("System.String"))
    Dim dataRow As DataRow = dataTable.NewRow
    dataRow(NameColumn) = Name 'exception here
```

Note that `Name` is a `string`. I've tried assigning values like "Bob" and "" to 'Name'. Also I've tried assigning "Bob" directly to `dataRow(NameColumn).
I get this exception;

> System.ArgumentException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>   Couldn't store <> in NameColumn Column.   Expected type is Int32. --->
>   System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

These work:

```
dataRow(NameColumn) = 123 'NO exception here
dataRow(NameColumn) = "123" 'NO exception here
```

Which is unexpected because I set the column type to `System.String`. The problem occurs only on the first column. The 2nd and 3rd work just fine:

```
Dim dataRow As DataRow = dataTable.NewRow
dataRow(AddressColumn) = "123 Sesame St." ' No exception here
Dim dataRow As DataRow = dataTable.NewRow
dataRow(CityColumn) = "Brooklyn" 'NO exception here
```

Is it the case that the first column is expected to be an int (an Id)?

EDIT:
It may be that the problem is with the first column only. I've amended the question to show more than one column. The 2nd, 3rd column work fine, though I only just discovered this because the exception caused the application to crash. Added code above to reflect this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240245/how-to-dynamically-create-columns-in-datatable-and-assign-values-to-it

Comment: what is the type, value and declaration for `Name`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that more directly (I merely implied by saying that I assigned "arbitrary strings"). Will add to the original.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code in a new project and it works. I would assume your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I've discovered more detail on the problem and changed the original question accordingly.

Comment: How is `NameColumn` defined?

Comment: added code for NameColumn

Comment: Note that the link posted by @Jim Hewitt does the answer, though it does explicitly state it. The first column needs to be "Id".